# Get posts of users and company which user is followed

Tags: neo4j

This node and relation is exist:

[image]

Company and user create post. User can follow users and companies.

I want to fetch the posts of users and companies which i follow them. with this query i can just fetch post os users:

```
MATCH (:User {id: '1'})-[:FOLLOWS]->(:User)<-[:POST]-(post) return post ORDER BY post.time DESC LIMIT 10
```

How to fetch both post of users and company which i follow?

Comment: My cypher is rusty - does `MATCH (:User {id: '1'})-[:FOLLOWS]->(u:User)<-[:POST]-(post) return u, post ORDER BY post.time DESC LIMIT 10` work?

Comment: @JonClements This is just return users of post. it's not my purpose.

Comment: Okay... so you need a `(:Company)` in there...

Comment: I don't know this is correct way or not, any one have another solution except this:  `MATCH (:User {id: '592417fba3d77ba013ca5850'})-[:FOLLOWS]->(:User)<-[:POST]-(post) RETURN post ORDER BY post.time DESC LIMIT 10
UNION
MATCH (:User {id: '592417fba3d77ba013ca5850'})-[:FOLLOWS]->(:Company)<-[:POST]-(post) RETURN post ORDER BY post.time DESC LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With removing label of user it's work as well.

```
MATCH (:User {id: '1'})-[:FOLLOWS]->()<-[:POST]-(post) return post ORDER BY post.time DESC LIMIT 10
```